# Haskell:lexical error in string/character literal at character 'd'

Tags: haskell, wit.ai

```
ruleYear :: Rule
ruleYear = Rule
{ name = "year"
 , pattern=[regex "[12]\d{3})|(([\.\/\-\'])[901]\d)"] 
 --pattern = [Predicate $ isIntegerBetween 1000 2100]
 , prod = \tokens -> case tokens of
   (token:_) -> do
     n <- getIntValue token
     tt $ year n
    _ -> Nothing
}
```

I am new to Haskell.
I was trying to modify the time parser in [duckling](https://github.com/facebookincubator/duckling).

I changed one of the several rules for parsing and received this error:

```
"lexical error in string/character literal at character 'd' " for line 4.
```

I am not sure what is the cause of this error and how to rectify it.

Answer (score 2):

It was fixed by using `\\` instead of `\` in the pattern.